# Rails deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I need to push my rails code into stating environment from github. And then deploy this app into engineyard in staging environment. Could some please give me step I need follow

Answer (score 3):

When you create an environment on Engine Yard, it guides you through setting up access to your git repository. I believe you can deploy from their web interface once you've setup the environment.

Also, [this post](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2010/01/ruby-on-rails/automatically-deploying-to-engine-yard-cloud) describes how to get automatic deployments when tests pass.

Comment: I adamantly second this.  Engine Yard costs a lot of money, and you are paying them to help with this.  Put in a ticket.